# Correcting words broken into syllables in a text

Tags: python, text, data-cleaning

I converted a .pdf file into .txt using Python. It is fairly easy to "clean" the text by removing special characters or certain characters that I don't want, however I have an interesting problem that I haven't managed to figure out other than manually.

The text is in German and some words are broken into syllables (they were probably like that in the original .pdf). So I have stuff like

```
Das ist die Belastung eines Grundstücks mit der Haftung für bestimmte, in der Regel wiederkeh-
rende Leistungen des jeweiligen Grundeigentümers.
```

It it not a good idea to just delete the hyphens because sometimes they make sense, such as in `Verkehrs- und Tarifverbund Stuttgart`.

Is there any way to avoid doing it manually? It happens in almost every sentence.

Comment: Can you leave all hyphens then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the word was split due to it being too long and at the end of the line, you should be able to just remove `"-\n"` (replace it with `""`).

If your document uses some other special character to indicate the end of line, you need to replace `\n` with that instead.